# Online/cloud special function calculations?

Tags: web-services, function, cloud, computer-science, distributed-computing

Anyone know of any webservice that provides calculations of special functions? For example, let's say my (unsophisticated) client needs to compute the Modified Bessel Function of Order zero at a list of x-values. I can write them some C or Python code to do that but they might find that a little scary. They would rather type it into a webpage. So I could write them a simple webapp. But then I wondered, doesn't such a thing already exist?

Anyone know of any? If not, someone should create it.

Comment: Who is "they", and isn't this what libraries are for?  What is the motivation/business case for some cloud service to heat their own silicon, computing your answers?

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is the website you are looking for, it can compute compute almost everything you want. It was created by the people who created Mathematica.